# IFRAME: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Tags: html, security, iframe, heroku, x-frame-options

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

I have this HTML code on a server (Heroku). From the iframe of www.example.com I click on the "login to google" button, but I get this error message:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options
```

I tried adding the `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="GOFORIT">` on the header of www.example.com but still doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" width=1000 height=1000></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may be have a look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options I tested and Its working fine on my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use real HTTP response headers. `<meta http-equiv>` isn't really equivalent.

How you set those depends on your server and/or server side programming language.

e.g. for Apache, with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header):

```
Header set X-Frame-Options GOFORIT
```

… will do the job.

Comment: Thanks. What would this HTTP response header be like for GWT?

Comment: The response header would be the same for any system — `X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT` — how you set response headers in GWT, I have no idea.

Comment: Just to be clear, should I include that header on www.example.com (server side) or on the website that contains the iframe (server side)?? Thanks again

Comment: The website that is being put in the frame.