# how to set the X-Frame-Options in a content hosted by github?

Tags: html, iframe, github

I want a html file to be loaded as iframe by any url, it's hosted by Github ..

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) doesn't work :

```
<?php
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); 
?>
```

And I suppose that we can't apply [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336851/iframe-refused-to-display-document-because-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options?lq=1) (mod_headers), so is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Support answer :

> We block iframes to prevent clickjacking attacks against our users. We
>   do this by sending the "X-Frame-Options: deny" header for every page. 
>   Clickjacking is a legitimate attack vector and at this time we do not
>   have plans to remove the "X-Frame-Options: deny" header or allow
>   exceptions for non-GitHub owned properties. It's unfortunate that such measures are necessary, but we have a responsibility to take all practical steps to protect our users.

Comment: Can someone confirm that this response is out of date? Currently it seems that the opposite is happening: github does not set these headers, and I would like to have them set to avoid clickjacking attacks. Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems incorrect to me, someone has clickjacked a github pages site of mine in an iframe

Answer (score 1):

As jeum explained, no dice with an iframe, it just won't work. If you could override the directive with a meta tag, it might work, [but you can't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx):

> Note that this token must be sent as a HTTP Header, and the directive will be ignored if found in a META HTTP-EQUIV tag.

So, it doesn't work with an iframe. But does it really have to be an iframe? Because loading a script will still work, so you could do something like this:

Script on your site (let's call it `load_content.js`):

```
var node = document.createElement('div')
node.innerHTML = '{place your code encoded as a JS string here}'
document.appendChild(node)
```

And then use it from other sites like this:

```
<script src="{URL to load_content.js}"></script>
```

Of course, this has some security implications for the sites on which you use it, but it might be sufficient for your needs.

---

OTOH, why don't you just host that content elsewhere? A small virtual server doesn't exactly cost a lot (unless you want tons of RAM and harddisk space) (I pay maybe 6€ per month or so), and even if you can't afford to pay any money, there are sites that let you host a few html pages for free, I think.

Comment: I agree with thejh: I had the same X-Frame-Options: deny issue with github, and ended up using Github Pages instead for file hosting, which is currently free.